# No service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IAuthorizationHeaderProvider' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-api

Edit: Used a pre release of a nuget, reverted back to older version and no longer got this error.

I am getting this error (Title), but cannot figure out what is wrong.
App works fine locally, publishes to Azure but gives me HTTP error 500 when trying to open the website.

I guess I might be missing a service in my Startup class?
This is the Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

namespace AppOwnsData
{
    using AppOwnsData.Models;
    using AppOwnsData.Services;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Get the scopes from the configuration (appsettings.json)
            var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
            
            // Add sign-in with Microsoft
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))

                // Add the possibility of acquiring a token to call a protected web API
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)

                // Enables controllers and pages to get GraphServiceClient by dependency injection
                // And use an in memory token cache
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
            
            
            
            
            // Register AadService and PbiEmbedService for dependency injection
            services.AddScoped(typeof(AadService))
                    .AddScoped(typeof(PbiEmbedService))
                    .AddScoped(typeof(PowerBiServiceApi));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            // Enables a UI and controller for sign in and sign out.
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            // Loading appsettings.json in C# Model classes
            services.Configure<AzureAd>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .Configure<PowerBI>(Configuration.GetSection("PowerBI"));
            
            /*// Add the UI support to handle claims challenges
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();*/
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting from the call stack in azure application insight:

> System.InvalidOperationException:    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
> Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService
> (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
> Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
> at
> Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c.b__1_0
> (Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph, Version=2.0.6.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a pre release of Microsoft.Identity.Web Nuget that caused this issue. After reverting back to an older version it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I too got this error. But I got this when I upgraded my Graph dependency to a higher version and still had an older version of Microsoft.Identity.Web in the project. Upgrading this to match the upgraded Graph dependency(Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient- 2.15.2) solved this issue in my case.